# How to use SHA512 method with JPA

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Hello I am trying to use the SHA512 function with criteriaBuilder.

Here is my code (which s not compiling due to "512" param):

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = builder.createQuery(User.class);
Root<User> userRoot = criteria.from(User.class);

criteria.where(builder.equal(userRoot.get("pseudo"), user.getPseudo()),
                        builder.equal(userRoot.get("password"),
                                builder.function("SHA2", String.class, userRoot.get("password"),"512")));
```

But hibernate do not accept the "512" parameter.
How can I use string litteral in expressions?

Thanks.

Comment: Here's the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#function-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression...-. As you see, the method expects Expressions as argument. "512" is a String, not an expression. How could you create an expression representing a literal String? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#literal-T-

Comment: Thanks it is exactly what I needed